# Is it reasonable to use Ethernet or USB to input video into FPGA?

Tags: fpga, embedded, ethernet

I want to use FPGA to do video processing and I need one video input and one output. The problem is most FPGA boards have one (HDMI or VGA) port and the price significantly rises with the boards which have two HDMI\VGA.
So my question is: Is it reasonable to use Ethernet or USB to input the video from PC to the FPGA considering the extra development complexity?
Edit: The video is 1080p and 30fps. The processing is rather light. By using Ethenet, I can go from a $400 board to a $150 board and I want to develop the interface myself to save cost

Comment: This is not how you define specifications for a project. Do you have some requirements?

Comment: USB and Ethernet don't transmit "Video".  They transmit a digitally encoded stream of data.

Comment: @R Drast. I know they transmit data. My question is if they transmit data fast enough and the extra steps you need to take in order to encode and decode the data at the source and the destination is worth svaing $300.

Comment: Ignore the pedants, we know what you mean. Yes, it's perfectly possible and reasonable, I've seen it done very successfully with Ethernet.

Comment: @DiBosco You can call me pedant (well, I am), but starting the design from this point is just wrong. Realtime processing of HD video data has to be defined from the aspect of the *processing* power at the very first place. And the factor setting the price will be this power, and not the interface.

Comment: To point you to something: Cypress makes adapter ICs from USB3 to other buses, the FX2 (8051 based, usb high speed) and FX3(arm926 based, usb super speed) series. I would recommend you use one of those to output USB to parallel video, then pipe the video into FPGA.

Comment: @Eugene Who said I called *you* a pedant? Guilty conscience? ;)

Comment: @DiBosco You said "pedants" in plural, and there were just two comments above :)

Comment: I was assuming there would be others! ;)

Comment: Another possibility is to wire a ARM SoC board's parallel display port to the FPGA.

Answer (score 3):

> The video is 1080p and 30fps.

So, assuming 8 bit per color channel, 3 color channels, that's

$$1920\cdot 1080\frac{\text{px}}{\text{frame}}\cdot 3\frac{\text{channel}}{\text{px}}\cdot 8\frac{\text{b}}{\text{channel}}\cdot30\frac{\text{frame}}{\text s}\approx 1.5 \,\frac{\text{Gb}}{\text s}\text.$$

That's more than Gigabit Ethernet can carry.

So, no, that's not possible with what you'd call "Ethernet", unless you compress the video, but then you need to do HD video decompression (and probably compression) on the FPGA, and that is not what one would call "light processing".

1.5 Gb/s is also faster than USB2 can work.

Thus, you're either up for USB3 or 10 Gigabit Ethernet. Both very complex buses, and I can't recommend integrating either in the first FPGA design you do – and based on the lack of concept in how you're trying to specify your project, I guess this is your first serious project.

HDMI/DVI/DP isn't all that complex a bus, if you restrict yourself to only one frame format. There's open source projects that implement that, so having an FPGA with such an interface built yourself sounds more promising than going for an universal bus.

Comment: In addition to this, if cost is a major factor, it seems that cards with multiple HDMI interfaces are currently significantly cheaper than boards that support 10 G Ethernet or USB 3

Answer (score 0):

Of course, it is possible. You have to implement USB/ETHERNET interface on your FPGA (or purchase the IP, though it is cheaper to buy a board) and also develop some custom IP (or a program if you use ZYNQ or Mircroblase) to convert input data into the pixel stream. From there on, you can use a standard approach for developing image processing IPs.

Comment: Is developing the interface straight forward for someone who doesn't have much experience with FPGAs?

Comment: I think developing anything on the FPGA is extremely difficult for someone who has little experience. Even getting to work "ready" examples is quite challenging. I also think that a $150 FPGA board will probably have Artrix smallest PL (if you mean Xilinx products). And this may be limited to the amount of resources needed for your image processing.

Comment: Realtime HD video processing (even the lightest one) with a $150 board seem unrealistic to me.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I agree. It just depends on what exactly means "light" processing.

Comment: @Naz By light processing I mean edge detection which is basically first turning into grayscale then 3*3 filtering then applying a threshold.

Comment: You need to know at least the part number to see how much resources are available. Then, it depends on your implementation. Turning into grayscale is negligible, applying a 3x3 Sobel should not require a lot. If you simply want to apply a threshold to your Sobel output - it's negligible too. I think you have a pretty good chance. On the other hand, @Marcus Muller is correct - the data throughput that you want requires USB3 or 10GB Eth to get it onto the chip.

Comment: @Alireza seriously, that sounds trivial to do on any GPU with a shader (and that includes integrated graphics chipsets these days). Why would you do it on an FPGA at all? In fact, I'd first verify you couldn't just do it in normal CPU software.

Comment: @Marcus Muller the goal is a much more complex video processing algorithm. It is currently being implemented on a high end CPU and GPU. I want to get started on FPGA with a trivial task and then scale it further.

Comment: well, but the scale is your main problem here, so hm, it doesn't work that way: If you need an extremely high-throughput bus, a cheap entry-level FPGA board won't do, from the start.